# Getting root of site

Tags: php

I've been struggling with this for quite a while now.

At my office, when we work with websites. we have a domain like this: http://www.domain.com/ each website is then stored here but within a subdirectory like so:

```
http://www.domain.com/dev1/ 
http://www.domain.com/dev2/
```

.. and so forth. Those pages are after completing their development, being moved to another website. My problem is, at the development stage i would like to be able to use some PHP command that would refer to that sites root dir, for paths etc.. In other words, if im developing a stylesheet in the directory of `/css/style.css` on the site of `http://www.domain.com/dev2/` i would like somesort of php command i can write so that it would refer to that sites root like this `$_SERVER['SOME_COMMAND']`."/css/style.css"

Is this even possible ?

Comment: Umm, if `Host: ` header is present (which is mandatory in HTTP 1.1), you can tried something like `"http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/css/style.css"`.

Comment: This all does not make sense (question including). How should anyone know what you define as a different website entry (unless you define it yourself explicitly, but in that case what is the question?)? Why do you even use this approach? Just run every site in their own domain. And test localhost...

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] will only give the domain name, eg `http://www.domain.com/`. This will not work properly when in a subdir like /dev1/. I could ofcourse just add /dev1/ but when the contents of the site is moved, you would have to go through all links and remove /dev1/ which is not intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define a path as a constant and use it.

Example: In your http://domain.com/dev2/index.php do this at the top:

```
define( 'ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) ); //This will set the path to our current folder in our constant "ROOT_PATH".
```

After that, you can use this constant in templates or other file includes, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>/css/style.css">
```

Addendum: As Jori said -in case it wasn't clear- you of course have to make sure that this constant variable is available to you. This can be achieved via the [include statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: So, how will this be available at any other page?

Comment: By regular file includes(?). I assume he's storing all (or at least most) settings and constants in the same place, otherwise you're bound to have to repeat yourself.

Comment: Okay, was a bit unclear (`index.php` is usually not the place for constant storage). If you edit your answer to include that, I will delete mine (also I think using `__DIR__` is better than `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: Might be a bit overkill, but sure, edited. About the `__DIR__` vs `dirname(__FILE__)`, I prefer the latter because of legacy support. I'm aware that `__DIR__` is supposed to be slightly faster, but I've never experienced this having any tangible impact performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the file-system path, you can use

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/path/to/resource.php"
```

Keep in mind that this will work only for file-system paths. It will not work for `sub.domain.com/path/to/resource`

I think, based on the info you have provided on your setup, if your website is setup with subdomains you should be fine using just the plain path to resource:

```
$url = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/css/style.css";
```

Otherwise, you'll have to add the subdomain directory to the path:

```
$url = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/dev1/css/style.css";
```

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot work here. `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` will point to `/var/www/vhosts/domain_com/domain.com/httpdocs` and not include the root directory of the site `dev1`, which will result in problems when moving the site from `domain.com/dev1` to a domainroot

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at PHPs "superglobals" (like `$_SERVER` and the like). There are predefined values in there that probably offer what you are looking for.

Comment: I down-voted your question, because it lacks reference and is unclear. You basically say: work it out yourself. Also it appears the questioner already is familiar with `$_SERVER`.